# Sort a list in Python with key argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I would like to sort a list of elements according to this statement:

```
i>=j  if(i_rank < j_rank OR ((i_rank == j_rank) AND (i_dinstance > j_dinstance)))
```

how would I need to state this in Python 3 with the sort() function?

Im getting that I can just use the key argument and make a function like:

```
   def sorter(x):
    if(i.rank < j.rank or ((i.rank == j.rank) and (i.distance > j.distance))):
        return ??
    else: 
        return ??

list.sort(reverse=True, key = sorter)
```

But I don't know what the argument for the sorter function would be? And the return of the function?

Thanks :-)

Comment: you've added a tag for python 2. but am i correct in reading that you really want a python 3 answer? Also, as a tip for constructing an answer for python 3, think of the key function as something that should return a hierarchical data for all entries, rather than doing a 1 against 1 comparison.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort, the key gets only a single value, not current and next like e.g. JavaScript. If you want to sort by rank then break ties on distance, you could return a tuple `(rank, distance)`.

Comment: `list.sort(reverse=True, key = lambda x: (x.rank, x.distance))` should work - if consecutive x.rank is equal it will sort ascending by distance - problem is: distance to what ... you can't do relative distances between points - more like overall distance of each points towards f.e. the center (0,0)#

Comment: The key function returns a key that is used for sorting instead of the original value. It does not do the comparison for the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass as the [`key` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions):

```
key=lambda x: (-x.rank, x.distance)
```

This would work, because comparing tuples uses a lexicographic ordering. Thus if the ranks are unequal, that would determine the order, and if they were equal, the distances determine the order.

Comment: i think it's `(-x.rank, x.distance)` a bigger value for distance is a bigger rank. But trying to think this through makes my head hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Full example for my comment

> `list.sort(reverse=True, key = lambda x: (x.rank, x.distance))` should work - if consecutive x.rank is equal it will sort ascending by distance - problem is: distance to what ... you can't do relative distances between points - more like overall distance of each points towards f.e. the center (0,0) [i.e. a precomputed distance...]

```
class p:
    def __init__(self, r, d):
        self.rank = r
        self.distance = d
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rank}|{self.distance}'
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

ranks = [1,2,3]
distances = [10,30,10]

data = [p(r,d) for r in ranks for d in distances]

print(data)

# sort by max rank, min distance
data.sort(key=lambda x:(-x.rank, x.distance))

print(data)
```

Output:

```
# created data
[1|10, 1|30, 1|10, 2|10, 2|30, 2|10, 3|10, 3|30, 3|10]

# sorted by max rank, min distance
[3|10, 3|10, 3|30, 2|10, 2|10, 2|30, 1|10, 1|10, 1|30]
```